# How can I assert that generic type T has specific property

Tags: typescript, abstract-class

I am creating an abstract class `BaseRepository` which extends `Repository`. T is passed into this abstract class. The method `main` takes a partial of `T` but `id` should be an optional prop of T. How can I assert T to have optional prop `id`?

```
export abstract class BaseRepository<T> extends Repository<T> {
  async main (changes: DeepPartial<T & { id?: number }>) {
    const p = this.create()
    Object.assign(p, changes)
    if (p && p.id) await this.update(p.id, p )
    const v = await this.save(p)
    return this.findOneOrFail({ where: v })
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do something like `BaseRepository<T extends InterfaceWithProperty>`

Answer (score 0):

Asserting that the generic type has an optional property is pretty simple.  Just define an interface that has the property and say that the type extends that interface.  This would look something like

```
interface Identifiable {
  id: number;
}

export abstract class BaseRepository<T extends Identifiable> extends Repository<T> {
  async main (changes: DeepPartial<T>) {
    const p = this.create();
    Object.assign(p, changes);

    if (p && p.id) {
      await this.update(p.id, p);
    }

    const v = await this.save(p);
    return this.findOneOrFail({ where: v })
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working. `this.update` 's second parameter is `T`, so it's complaining that it can't extend E.

Comment: `this.update()` hasn't changed from the snippet you submitted.

Comment: If you're seeing an error in the snippet you submitted (other than the typing question), include that in the question along with whatever methods are causing the error and I'll see if I can help.